# Running class methods in cascade

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have a system that was designed to do a kind of cascading - get the sequence of methods called upon success of the previous condition.

The example is the below code, which I presume it's not a best practice for doing this, so would be great if I could get some suggestions to refactor this, probably using a design pattern or a different than this system.

```
<?php
class Model
{
    public function isOk()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class OtherClass
{
    public function isOk()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class AnotherClass
{
    public function verifies()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class Sequence
{
    public function fire()
    {

        $model = new Model();
        if($model->isOk()) {

            $otherclass = new OtherClass();
            if($otherclass->isOk()) {

                $anotherclass = new AnotherClass();
                if($anotherclass->verifies()) {

                    echo "We're done with the sequence.";

                    return true;

                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}

$sequence = new Sequence();
echo $sequence->fire();
?>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the Command along with Chain of Responsibility patterns?

Comment: Hi Henrique, thanks for the suggestion but in this case, the chain of responsibility pattern doesn't fit the purpose.

Comment: And why not? Could you explain? I cant't see any reason, at first...

Comment: What is intended is that the class method called must return true in order to the following to be able to proceed. A false is an overall failure and the script execution must terminate. From what I understand about the CR d pattern, his is not the case, but please correct me if I'm not understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid deep nesting of if/else statements to enhance the readability. One way is to use early return:

```
class Test1
{
    public function isOk()
    {
        echo 'Test1';
        return true;
    }
}

class Test2
{
    public function isOk()
    {
        echo 'Test2';
        return true;
    }
}

class Sequence
{
    public function fire()
    {
        $test1 = new Test1();
        if (!$test1->isOk()) {
            return false;
        }

        $test2 = new Test2();
        if (!$test2->isOk()) {
            return false;
        }

        echo "We're done with the sequence.";
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you need it more dynamically you could use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) or [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

```
class Sequence
{

    protected $sequence = array(
        array('Test1', 'isOk'),
        array('Test2', 'isOk'),
    );

    public function fire()
    {
        foreach ($this->sequence as $callback) {
            if (!call_user_func(array(new $callback[0], $callback[1]))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        echo "We're done with the sequence.";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The second example looks more clean but I have some "stuff" going inside each sequence so probably your first example will be the option. I'll see if someone comes up with other solutions and will accept the one it'll go better with my problem. Thanks!